# Php to only show the YEAR from sql DATETIME

Tags: php, sql, datetime, foreach

I have a function that I am using for a foreach loop that the 3 latest posts from the mySQL DB.

```
function latest_posts_footer(PDO $dbh) {
    global $dbh;

    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("
        SELECT      *
        FROM        posts
        ORDER BY    post_date DESC
        LIMIT       0, 3
    ");
    $stmt->execute();
    return $stmt->fetchAll();
}
latest_posts_footer($dbh);
$latest_posts_footer = latest_posts_footer($dbh);
```

The post_date type is DATETIME which works correctly.

I know that the query: `SELECT YEAR(post_date) FROM posts;` gives me the year out my post_date.

To just show the raw DATETIME I can simply do:

[image: the loop]

Which would bring me the output: *2000-01-01 00:00:00*.

How do I **only get the YEAR** from that output with PHP? Help is more than appreciated. Thanks!

*P.S. I've already looked into previous posts regarding the same thing, but they wont help.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you exactly mean by `YEAR`?

```
$yearOnly = date("Y", $lpf['post_date']);
```

**[PHP DATE Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)**

Comment: I ment exactly what you thought I did! Dumb me that I didn't think about the manual.. Do you by any chance know how to convert it into swedish months? Thanks @johnwoo

Comment: @Nworks I'm not sure give this a try [*Click the link*](http://www.solutioncottage.com/ShowSolution.aspx?solID=222)

Comment: @Nworks, oh try this `$swedenFormat = date("d F Y", $lpf['post_date']);` . This is a sweden format, `18 December 2009`. Right?

Comment: It gives me: Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in C:\Users\Nabil\Dropbox\php\html\nworks\index.php on line 184 When I do `$year = date("Y", $lpf['post_date']);`

Comment: @Nworks what is the format of your date when you tried to echo it?

Comment: `echo("$month $day, $year");` Btw it's not the format I am after it's the language :D @JohnWoo

Answer (score 5):

```
$year = date("Y", strtotime($lpf['post_date']));

echo $year;
```

Answer (score 0):

here's a hint

```
 $date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", "2068-06-15");
 echo $date->format("Y");
```

unless i'm misunderstanding something here